# Edit dynamic details of Data in Asp.net Mvc using Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

```
<!-- Product Details.cshtml -->
@model Test.Web.Models.Product

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}
<br />
<h2 class="text-info">Product details</h2>
<partial name="_ModelViewPartial" model="@Model" />
<br />
```

```
<!-- _ModelViewPartial.cshtml -->
@model dynamic

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m);
}
```

I'm passing models from dynamic and able to show them on view like this. I want to design view like add labels class col-2 but don't know how edit while doing like this. I don't want to hard code details pages for all models so decided it to do like this without knowing how to do it. Also how can i hide ID parameter in this method?

Thanks~

Comment: You can create editortemplates for each of your models. When you pass the model from the controller, the relevant editortemplate based on the model will be displayed. You cannot hide the parameters in the Get Request, you can use a post request

Comment: i want to avoid using editortemplates. You have to write for each model. I am trying to write a partial page and pass different models there

Comment: It will never be working with dynamic model.

Comment: I can pass different models with it and show but can't design with this.
All parameters of model are visible even id and can be edited. I am not able edit like
`<input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />`
It auto-places in a way that I don't know how to edit.